# obtaining "4 Hz modulation energy"

Tags: matlab, modulation

Could anybody tell me a method to calculate the "4 Hz modulation energy" for a speech signal?

Thanks.

EDIT

I get some details : 4 Hz modulation energy: Speech has a characteristic energy modulation peak around the 4 Hz syllabic rate [3]. We use a portion of the MFCC algorithm [4] to convert the audio signal into 40 perceptual channels. We extract the energy in each band, bandpass filter each channel with a second order filter with a center frequency of 4 Hz, then calculate the short-term energy by squaring and smoothing the result. We normalize each channel's 4 Hz energy by the overall channel energy in the frame, and sum the result from all channels. Speech tends to have more modulation energy at 4Hz than music does.

Comment: Can you give a reference as to where this terminology is used? Does [this help?](http://www.auditory.org/mhonarc/2005/msg00222.html)

Comment: I already checked this link but it did not give me a big push

Comment: Does my additional information start "pushing" ? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The link in my comment](http://www.auditory.org/mhonarc/2005/msg00222.html) suggests the following:

> I would recommend first extracting the envelope by using either a halfwave
>   rectification (i.e., replace all the negative values in the time waveform
>   with zeros) or a Hilbert Transform and then lowpass filtering the waveform
>   at around 50 Hz (the lowpass is optional if you only care about the 4 Hz
>   component).   Once you have the envelope, simply do an fft (making sure
>   that your frequency resolution is at least 1 Hz) and look for the energy
>   around 4 Hz.  If any of these steps don't seem obvious too you, let me know
>   and I can send you some Matlab code.

So, what that means is you need to take your speech $s[n]$ and find the envelope:

$$
e[n] = \left | s[n] + j{\bf H}\left[s[n]\right] \right |
$$

where ${\bf H}$ is the Hilbert transform of your speech signal.

Then, take the FFT and look at the bin at 4Hz.