# 4 Hertz Modulation Energy

Tags: spectrogram

I am trying to distinguish between speech signals and music signals using feature extraction and SVM. I am looking for features to include for this purpose.

While going through literature, I came across something called '4 Hz modulation energy' that is distinctively present in speech and not in music, but was unable to find any further literature about it. I would like to know the reason for this energy present in speech. References to the same would be very helpful.

Also, I tried plotting the spectrogram of a music signal and a speech signal, such that the frequency bin size was 1Hz (which would involve me taking a 44100 point FFT where 44100 was my sampling frequency). On visually inspecting the spectrogram at 4Hz, such a 4Hz peak of energy was not apparent to me for a speech signal as compared to a music signal. When I include the 4 Hz modulation energy as a feature per frame in my SVM, it indeed reduces the accuracy of prediction.

As such I would like to know how this energy arises, and would like to know more about it.

---

Edit : [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3830943/) answers some of my questions.

Comment: [That question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8861/4298) and its answer might be helpful.

Comment: I have encountered the question that you mentioned before, and while it did help me to compute/obtain the 4 Hz modulation energy, it still doesn't explain what it is, why it occurs and why I am not finding it in my samples of speech.

Comment: Edit : [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3830943/) answers some of my questions.